Intersection of Two Random Curves with Given Density Functions
I have been working on a personal project for the past few weeks and have encountered a serious roadblock. Essentially, what I have are two curves whose $y$-values are generated from density functions (heretofore pdfs) at discrete points along the $x$-axis. What I want to determine is a probabilistic expression for the first point that these two curves are likely to cross. Let's suppose that $p^1_{n}(v)$ is the pdf that curve 1 takes on a value between $v$ and $v+{\rm d}v$ at the $n^{\rm th}$ point and $p^2_{n}(v)$ being the same for curve 2. Both pdfs describe independent random variables. Additionally, I know that
$$
\left<p^1_{n}(v)\right> \propto n+c\quad\text{and}\quad\left<p^2_{n}(v)\right> \propto n^2
$$
where angled brackets denote ensemble averages and $c\in\Bbb{R}^+$. With this condition, I know that these two curves must meet at some $n\neq 0$. However, an answer to this question for general functional dependence of the ensemble averages would be nice.
So far I came up with the idea that, since the two pdfs are independent, the probability for a crossing would be given by something like,
$$
p_n^{\rm cross}(v) \propto p_n^1(v)\int_v^\infty p_n^2(v'){\rm d}v'
$$
since this would describe the probability that curve 1 has value $v$ times the probability that curve 2 has value above $v$. However, since I want to impose the condition that the crossing hasn't already happened, I also thought that we would want to multiply by the probability that a crossing didn't happen on the previous $n$,
$$
p_n^{\rm cross}(v) \propto p_n^1(v)\left(\int_v^\infty p_n^2(v'){\rm d}v'\right)\left(1-\int_0^\infty p_{n-1}^{\rm cross}(v'){\rm d}v'\right)
$$
and any previous possible crossings would be taken care of by recursion. But upon evaluating this numerically, those two expressions evaluate to the exact same.
Essentially, I have found that the probability that the crossing happens does not decrease after the crossing is expected to happen. I don't know if anyone has any insights or can tip me off towards something I've missed, but any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
